# How do I present data relevant to the logged-in user based on Group?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm a total newbie to django so this may well have an obvious answer but so far google hasn't worked out for me.

I have this skeleton application using Django 1.8.
I have a simple model that has an owner field which is a ForeignKey to Group.
When a user is logged in I would like to show only the items that he/she has access to. Access being determined by the fact that the user belongs to the same group.

model.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,db_index=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from django.views import generic

from .models import Device
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
     """
     This renders the index page listing the devices a user can view
     """
     template_name = 'devices/index.html'
     context_object_name = 'devices_list'

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
          return super(IndexView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

     def get_queryset(self):
         """
         Return the devices visible to the logged-in user
         """
         return devices=Device.objects.all()
```

What I don't seem to be able to figure out is what to put in the .filter() instead of .all() call in my get_queryset method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated based on Jean-Michel's feedback.

I don't have a Django environment in front of me at the moment, but this might be a good start:

```
    return devices=Device.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user.groups.all())
```

Alternatively, Django's ORM uses double underscore (`__`) to access field lookups. These can be used to get values greater than (`__gt`), or in a list (`__in`) amongst other lookups ([see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)).

```
    return devices=Device.objects.filter(owner__in=self.request.user.groups.all())
```

This kind of depends on where the user object is located. I'm assuming the logged in user is kept as a class attribute, i.e., `self.user`. Per, Jean-Michel's comments, the user object is attached to the request. So we can access it from `self.request.user.groups`.

Finally, you can access specific fields on models using the double underscore notation as well (`__`), this example is from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/):

```
# Find all Articles for any Reporter whose first name is "John".
>>> Article.objects.filter(reporter__first_name='John')
[<Article: John's second story>, <Article: This is a test>]
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer in the right direction. What I was missing in my understanding was the field__in syntax. Now that I've understood this concept I can progress to the next hurdle (what ever that will be).

The final answer was:
`return Device.objects.filter(owner__in=self.request.user.groups.all())`

Comment: @Jean-MichelRubillon, glad it got you going in the right direction. I updated the answer based on your feedback and included additional references. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @TechMedicNYC for a comprehensive response and the nudge in just the right direction.